# Routing system uses default route instead of specific one

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have problem with routing in my mvc app. I have my core app with ProductsController and extension that is loaded in "PreApplicationStartMethod". In this extenstion i register route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ProductDetails",
    url: "Products/Details/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "StandardProductsDetails", action = "Details" },
    namespaces: new []{ "Shop.Controllers" }
);
```

And in my core app im not registering specific route for ProductsController but I have a general route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new[] { "Shop.Controllers" }
);
```

Now when I enter /Products/Details/1 in web browser im redirectd to ProductsController.

Oderd of adding routes is specific first, general last. I've checked routes table and my route is existing in it.

Comment: What happens if you copy the route just before the default route instead of registering in `PreApplicationStartMethod`? I suspect this event is happening too early in the pipeline (per [this post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/16/three-hidden-extensibility-gems-in-asp-net-4.aspx/) it happens before the code in `App_Code` is compiled) for it to be useful to register routes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using two projects here, if you are using then make the project as startup project(by right click) which you want to hit first.